# try/catch open/closed principle violation

Tags: c++, object-oriented-design, design-principles

I have three or more different custom exceptions that a class can throw and I need to use try/catch in order to discover which exception was thrown.

In my point of view this piece of code violates the Open/Closed principle, because if we look the definition we see:

> "software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open
>   for extension, but closed for modification"

```
try {
    // something that throws
} catch (const FooException& e) {
    // ...
} catch (const BarException& e) {
    // ...
} catch (const BizException& e) {
    // ...
} catch (...)
{
    // ...
}
```

What if I need to catch another exception? I will need to insert another catch statement, right?

Is there another way for doing this? Or the language is somehow forcing me to violate the principle?

Comment: This doesn't violate the Open/Closed principal. The "closed for modification" part doesn't mean "don't modify the code". It means "don't modify the original intent of this class." To properly answer this question we need more context for the code you posted. Can you briefly describe what this class does?

Comment: There's nothing more to add, the method will store the information about the exception to log after.

Comment: You need to give us a better description of what your class does, and what this method is doing. Depending on what it does or is meant to do, this might or might not violate the Open/Closed Principle.

Comment: Throwing a new exception breaks the class's specification. You'd have the exact same problem if you reported errors through the method's return value - the client code will only check for the error codes you defined, and adding a new one will break things either at compile time or at run time.

Comment: @Greg:I always interpreted the "closed for modification" to mean exactly that you shouldn't need to modify the code. Once any change occurs in a class then you have to retest the entire class and any classes that have dependencies on that class. In a typical commercial product that might not matter much, but in environments where verification and validation are strict it matters a whole lot because a small change could force you into having to do a lot of regression testing. However, the OP's specific example is talking about a deficiency/change in the code and not really an extension, IMO.

Comment: I don't think Open/Closed applies to your example. You aren't creating a new subclass and you aren't extending functionality. You are simply making a change to existing code either because of a new requirement or because of a deficiency in the code.

Comment: @Dunk: From [oodesign.com](http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html): "The Open Close Principle states that the design and writing of the code should be done in a way that __new functionality should be added with minimum changes in the existing code.__" It doesn't state that code, once written, should never be changed.

Comment: @Greg:I'll one-up your source and use Robert C. Martin ("Uncle Bob") for my definition:) "They are Closed for Modification.
The source code of such a module is inviolate. No one is allowed to make source code changes to it."

Comment: It appears that Bertrand Meyer is credited with coining the term open-closed principle. His definition : The idea was that once completed, the implementation of a class could only be modified to correct errors; new or changed features would require that a different class be created.  As stated on Wikipedia. I think the pair of Bertand Meyer and Robert C. Martin trumps oodesign.com by quite a large margin.  Sort of like 4 aces versus a pair of 2's.

Comment: And their definitions don't reflect reality. Source code changes. Every principle needs to be balanced with pragmatism. Sometimes the purpose of a class _does_ change. Requiring a name change for a simple addition is silly. At every point of change you should see if another class is needed, which is the very essence of the Open/Closed Principle --- not that a class can't be changed. If it changes too often it might be a sign that you've violated the Single Responsibility Principle. It's a judgment call, not law.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on how you plan to recover from these exception, meaning what code is executed in the catch statements. 
If it's the same for all 3 exceptions, you could create a superclass for them and catch the superclass. If your method has to throw a new exception, just make it extend the superclass and it would still be caught by the caller and would not need any changes in the client code.

Generally tough, if a method throws that many exceptions it's usually a hint that the method does to much and you might want to consider refactoring it.

If you want a more detailed answer, it would be helpfull to see a complete code listing of your method.

Comment: A method won't throw all but can throw one of those just like it could throw `std::runtime_error` or `std::logic_error`. The idea is just like I commented above is to gather informations about the exception and log after depending of each exception.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to *log* each exception - in some way depending on its specific type, you can split that concern out into a dedicated exception logger.

First, you need a base type - let's assume you just subclass `std::exception`. Now, your main code can just be:

```
try {
    // something that throws
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
    ExceptionLogger::log(e);
    throw;
}
```

Have the `log` method use `dynamic_cast` to handle all the specific subtypes it knows, and you have just one place to modify when a new exception type is added.

NB. I made `log` a static method here, but you could reasonably have a local (or data member, or ...) `ExceptionLogger` instance configured differently per component, connected to a different output/target logger, etc. etc.

---

There are essentially two implementation options for the `log` method itself:

1. hand-craft something that knows each derived type, and what to do with it. This can use `dynamic_cast` explicitly:

   ```
   void ExceptionLogger::log(std::exception const &ex) {
     if ((FooException const *e = dynamic_cast<FooException const *>(&ex))) {
       // handle foo
     } else if ((BarException const *e = dynamic_cast<BarException const *>(&ex))) {
       // handle bar
     } // else ... etc.
   }
   ```

   (as you probably noticed, this is actually uglier than the original code, so all we've done is de-couple it from the code you didn't want to modify), or you can move *exactly* the same try/catch arrangement out of your function - just re-throw in the try block.
2. Write a generic typeid-based dispatcher, so you can de-couple the per-exception-type code from both your original function *and* the dispatcher. This is a form of ad-hoc visitation (you're essentially writing a `visit` method for each interesting subclass of `std::exception`). Now, you can register each new handler externally, without changing either your original code or the `ExceptionLogger` itself.

Comment: Nice approach but I'm wondering how the `log` method will be? `switch`, `if`s? How I will handle this using `dynamic_cast` and verifying each one of them?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I didn't understand the 2º.

Comment: I don't have time to describe it in detail now (and it's getting close to off-topic anyway), but search for "c++ ad-hoc visitor" or similar and you should find it. Might originally be from Alexandrescu's _Modern C++ Design_ and the Loki library, but I can't check right now.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an OCP-conforming way of handling an unspecified list of exceptions, then you can consider "chain of responsibility". But it's not clear from your question whether your code is specified to handle "an arbitrary set of exceptions, each in a different way, all of which will be specified in future and is subject to change", or whether the fixed list of three that it currently handles is a fundamental and reliable part of the design.

Adding another exception to the list of things that your code needs to handle isn't "extending" the code you have, it is "modifying" it. So if you're in the former, flexible, case then you have an OCP violation on your hands because you'll need to modify your code to handle an anticipated change. If you're in the latter case, perhaps because `Foo`, `Bar` and `Biz` represent the only three legal base classes for all exceptions that your code is permitted to handle different from the `...` case, then you might be OK.

Provided that "something that throws" has a well-defined and stable interface, then you don't ever need to add to the list of exceptions you handle. So your code isn't in itself a violation of OCP. Part of OCP is that you don't make backward-incompatible changes to existing interfaces that people rely on throughout the code. Throwing a new exception is a backward-incompatible interface change, it is modification.

If "something that throws" has a badly documented interface, or one subject to change in future, such that it can suddenly start throwing something it didn't throw before, then you do have a violation of OCP: "something" violates it by being open to modification. These violations tend to spread, so your code will have to violate it too.

If "something" is well-specified, but your code is using information about "something" that goes beyond its interface, then you have a problem with over-coupling between components. I'm unsure whether to consider that *also* an OCP violation, I'm not really in a position where the taxonomy of issues beyond the first is important to me ;-)

Note that in any case a complete commitment to OCP is a reasonably high standard. You might find that "I'm not going to write the code this way because it violates the Open/Closed Principle" simply doesn't suit you or your colleagues. Which is not necessarily to say you should be ignorant of whether you're violating it or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think Phil's answer should get accepted in the end because it contains the best info. But to just answer your `Is there another way for doing this?` question specifically: here is another way which seperates the exception handling part pretty well, though it depends on the exact situation how usefull it is

```
template< class Fun >
void TryCatch( Fun f )
{
  try {
      f()
  } catch (const FooException& e) {
      // ...
  } catch (const BarException& e) {
      // ...
  } catch (const BizException& e) {
      // ...
  } catch (...)
  {
      // ...
  }
}

void DoSomething()
{
  TryCatch( []()
    {
      //do something
    } );     
}
```